# Pandas - Optimizing dataframe multiple conditions reverse nested loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization, vectorization

So I have this piece of code I wrote that works well. However, it's way too slow, as I run this code multiple tens of thousands of time frequently. I would like help to optimize it with vectorized operations, but I'm having trouble finding ways to do so, as I'm not an absolute expert in pandas yet.

```
def slowFunctionToOptimize():
    # Variables definition
    minVolume = 2000
    exchange1 = 'binance'
    exchange2 = 'bitmart'
    volEx1Str = 'volume_' + exchange1
    volEx2Str = 'volume_' + exchange2
    threshold = 15.0
    minDuration = 10.0

    # See below for an example dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep='|')
    
    indicesLst = dataset.index.values
    minIndexLst = indicesLst[0]
    
    # Get all indices that exceed or are equal to the specified threshold,
    # and normalize with the first index value to work with "iloc" later on
    indicesThresh = dataset.index[dataset.diffprice >= threshold].values - minIndexLst
    
    pv = None
    prevEndIndex = len(dataset)
    
    # Get the largest possible amount of rows (sequential order) based on the volume mean
    #  of the two exchanges, where the first value exceed or is equal to the threshold
    for startInd in indicesThresh:
        for endInd in range(prevEndIndex, 0, -1):
            if endInd - startInd < minDuration:
                break
    
            dfTmp = dataset.iloc[startInd:endInd, :]
            avgVolume1 = dfTmp[volEx1Str].mean()
            avgVolume2 = dfTmp[volEx2Str].mean()
            if avgVolume1 > minVolume and avgVolume2 > minVolume:
                # Get the final result.
                pv = dfTmp.copy()
                break
    
        # Largest amount of rows found, exiting
        if pv is not None:
            break
    
        prevEndIndex = startInd
    
    if pv is None:
        print('No combination could be found for this iteration.')
        return
    
    return pv
```

Here's the "example.csv" dataset:

| (index) | volume_binance | volume_bitmart | diffprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17039 | 69971.80688 | 4327.175492 | 47.48390871854886 |
| 17040 | 153370.133088 | 3528.694959 | 48.53994165659899 |
| 17041 | 76187.307674 | 2392.877003 | 47.29860035648541 |
| 17042 | 104401.51896 | 3502.658194 | 47.531388100324854 |
| 17043 | 61927.974127999994 | 2955.0013229999995 | 48.09375550725489 |
| 17044 | 66800.204432 | 2997.791962 | 48.53118830843571 |
| 17045 | 67560.20299500001 | 1552.265414 | 49.42801256594155 |
| 17046 | 134373.92478899998 | 3411.825602 | 50.17573122058736 |
| 17047 | 57268.227960000004 | 408.52263999999997 | 48.42945038122994 |
| 17048 | 81061.533276 | 2841.843586 | 49.37624085103861 |
| 17049 | 71169.214896 | 2681.685852 | 49.881164587046925 |
| 17050 | 52260.95781099999 | 2159.977762 | 49.72388813015853 |
| 17051 | 29749.781696 | 2769.8278600000003 | 50.014876524843785 |
| 17052 | 117725.19930000001 | 3218.053416 | 50.38916887841825 |
| 17053 | 102968.103323 | 394.730464 | 51.604463023668465 |
| 17054 | 49060.105344 | 0.0 | 51.27689583770968 |
| 17055 | 195587.92349000002 | 0.0 | 52.2316844839041 |
| 17056 | 198279.83096000002 | 362.99232800000004 | 53.64218226150563 |
| 17057 | 114223.564344 | 1913.151606 | 55.15065710504449 |
| 17058 | 130622.16151599998 | 0.0 | 55.1193699237017 |
| 17059 | 74873.30932900001 | 0.0 | 53.25227963525835 |
| 17060 | 69200.632056 | 0.0 | 53.53227771010961 |
| 17061 | 53494.92473600001 | 0.0 | 54.232051635006584 |
| 17062 | 56407.084068000004 | 0.0 | 52.72771332505377 |
| 17063 | 69346.222104 | 0.0 | 52.55673222390317 |
| 17064 | 47778.53641 | 0.0 | 52.23429951690821 |
| 17065 | 78987.33048 | 0.0 | 51.71210206415115 |
| 17066 | 49213.878500000006 | 0.0 | 51.116439382586535 |
| 17067 | 77530.21365599999 | 188.51300000000003 | 50.44907946170143 |

Here's the expected output (return variable "pv" inside the function):

| (index) | volume_binance | volume_bitmart | diffprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17039 | 69971.80688 | 4327.175492 | 47.48390871854886 |
| 17040 | 153370.133088 | 3528.694959 | 48.53994165659899 |
| 17041 | 76187.307674 | 2392.877003 | 47.29860035648541 |
| 17042 | 104401.51896 | 3502.658194 | 47.53138810032485 |
| 17043 | 61927.974128 | 2955.0013229999995 | 48.09375550725489 |
| 17044 | 66800.204432 | 2997.791962 | 48.53118830843571 |
| 17045 | 67560.20299500001 | 1552.265414 | 49.42801256594155 |
| 17046 | 134373.92478899998 | 3411.825602 | 50.17573122058736 |
| 17047 | 57268.22796 | 408.52264 | 48.42945038122994 |
| 17048 | 81061.533276 | 2841.843586 | 49.37624085103861 |
| 17049 | 71169.214896 | 2681.685852 | 49.881164587046925 |
| 17050 | 52260.95781099999 | 2159.977762 | 49.72388813015853 |
| 17051 | 29749.781696 | 2769.8278600000003 | 50.014876524843785 |
| 17052 | 117725.1993 | 3218.053416 | 50.38916887841825 |
| 17053 | 102968.103323 | 394.730464 | 51.60446302366847 |
| 17054 | 49060.105344 | 0.0 | 51.27689583770968 |
| 17055 | 195587.92349 | 0.0 | 52.2316844839041 |
| 17056 | 198279.83096 | 362.992328 | 53.64218226150563 |
| 17057 | 114223.564344 | 1913.151606 | 55.15065710504449 |
| 17058 | 130622.16151599998 | 0.0 | 55.1193699237017 |

Comment: I can't see your 'pv' column, did you put it in the question ?

Comment: "pv" isn't a column, it's the return variable inside the function!

Comment: my bad, I didn't understand that your function extracts a sub-table from your original dataframe

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to optimize this code:

1. Calculating the mean more efficiently by adding "cumulative volume" columns for bitmart and binance.

| volume1 | cumulative volume1 | volume 2 | cumulative volume2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 9 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 13 | 4 | 9 |

The average volume is then simply `dataset['cumulative volume'][startInd] - dataset['cumulative volume'][endInd]`

2. Update only the data you need : copying dataframes is quite inefficient, so you should avoid updating `dfTmp` all the time. Simply keep track of `startInd` and `endInd` and use the previous trick to calculate the average volumes

There are probably some other tricks you can use, but without knowing the exact type of data you are using I don't think I can help you more than that

Comment: The type of data is np.float64.

Comment: I'll use the other tricks you proposed, as they seem like good ideas. Keep me in touch once or if you find something else to do with the type of data!